# Redox Titration in investigating change of Iron in Avocado

Tags: redox, titration

I'm trying to investigate the change in iron in an avocado as it ripens. I'm planning on using redox titration but still a bit unsure of how to carry out the investigation (method). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot do titration to determine iron content with redox methods because the amount of iron is very very small in fruits. Search for spectrophotometric methods.

Comment: @M.Farooq Your comment should probably be posted as an answer (with approx. LODs/LOQs, if possible).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do simple volumetric redox titration to determine iron content because the amount of iron is very very small in a single fruit (on the order of fraction of a milligram). Imagine what would be the buret reading? Classical methods are good for large concentrations >> 1% wt/wt

With such small quantities, UV-Vis absorption spectroscopy or atomic spectroscopy comes to our rescue. Among the common (cheap) methods, iron- 1,10 phenanthroline complex method is often used for educational purposes.